# UITableView update data on row selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that get its data from an array and the array contains the filenames of a directory.

I am trying to make user edit filename on row selection.

My code is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self editChattWithName:[self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:indexPath];
    [self.tabView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)editChattWithName:(NSString*)name atIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIAlertView* editAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:nil
        message:@"Edit FileName"
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
        otherButtonTitles:@"Update", nil];
    [editAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

    UITextField* nameField = [editAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    [nameField setPlaceholder:@"New FileName"];
    [nameField setText:name]; 
    [editAlert show];
    [editAlert release];

    NSString *newFileName = nameField.text;
    [editAlert showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
            if (buttonIndex == 0) {   }
            else if (buttonIndex == 1) { 
                NSError *error;
                // Edit filename inside directory
                [fm moveItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",directory,name] toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",directory,newFileName] error:&error];
                // Update value inside array
                [self.listArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newChatName];
                // reload table data to show new filename
                [self.tabView reloadData];
                NSLog(@"Old Filename: %@%@",directory,name);
                NSLog(@"New Filename: %@%@",directory,newFileName);
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
                }
            }];
}
```

The issue is that `name` and `newFileName` are having the same value `name` and that is resulting an error with NSFileManager saying that the file already exists.

I have tried removing `[nameField setText:name]` but the problem was still there.

I am out of luck and not able to find the issue, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you already know that the method `moveItemAtPath:toPath:` is causing the error only in case that the old and the new file name are identical then it should be quite easy to catch this error:

```
if (![newFileName isEqualToString:name]) {
    [fm moveItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",directory,name] toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",directory,newFileName] error:&error];
}
```

Now your file will only me moved (i.e. renamed) when the new file name differs from the old name.

---

**Edit:**

Furthermore, if you want to get the new file name that the user just entered in the alert view you should put this line:

```
NSString *newFileName = nameField.text;
```

in your completion block. Otherwise it will be set when the alert view is first displayed and hence have its initial value. To put it all together:

```
[editAlert showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) { 
        NSString *newFileName = nameField.text;
        NSError *error;
        // Edit filename inside directory
        if (![newFileName isEqualToString:name]) {
            [fm moveItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",directory,name] toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",directory,newFileName] error:&error];
        }
        // Update value inside array
        [self.listArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newChatName];
        // reload table data to show new filename
        [self.tabView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

---

**Supplement:**

In order to not confuse other users it should be noted that `showWithCompletion:` is *not* a native `UIAlertView` method. An Objective-C category has been created to extend `UIAlertView` with this method. An example can be found [here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/04/ios-programming-recipe-22-simplify-uialertview-with-blocks/).

Comment: `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` method is not the issue. The issue (according to logs) is that `newFileName` is having the same string as `name` which is causing `NSFileManager` error: File already exists. The names should not be identical i am writing different string in the textfield.

Comment: From what I can see `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` is the only `NSFileManager` method that you are calling so I see no reason why `NSFileManager` should throw an error if not for this method. Have you tried inserting that if-statement?

Comment: Especially because you wrote in your question: *I have tried removing [nameField setText:name] but the problem was still there.* So obviously the error doesn't have anything to do with setting the nameField's text.

Comment: `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` is not a NSFileManager method but `moveItemAtPath:toPath:`is. And i don't think you get what i am trying to do. I want when user click on a cell an alert with UITextField will show to edit that cell. By editing the cell i have to rename that file inside the directory and also change the value of it inside `NSArray` and then reload data. so basically adding that `if statement` will just return false because the main problem is that UITextField text `newFileName` is for some reason getting the same string as `name`.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. I just copied the wrong method name in my reply and my comment. Of course, I was referring to the `NSFileManager` method `moveItemAtPath:toPath:`. My suggested code included the correct method name though. I have updated my answer, corrected the method name and added another suggestion for getting the new file name.